# Css: make flex grandchild fill its parent

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following structure:

```css
    .root {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      min-height:80vh;
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    
    .mainContent {
        background-color: aliceblue;
        flex: 1 1 0%;
    }
    
    .iWantToBeBig {
       height:100%; /* does not work... */
       background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="root">
       <div>Irrelevant header</div>
       <div class="mainContent">
           <div class="iWantToBeBig">but I stay small</div>
       </div>
       <div>Irrelevant footer</div>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, I have the limitation that I cannot (and I would like not to) influence the root and mainContent elements. Those come from third party libraries, and look like working fine: the header and the footer stay on the top and on the bottom of the root window, and are content sized. The mainContent div takes the rest of the available space. So far, all ok.

My problem is that my grandchild of the flexbox (this comes from my code) does not get the height of its parent. If I understand it correctly, this is because mainContent has no height set, but flex-basis instead. But still, I do not really know how to have iWanntToBeBig element get the whole height of its parent, without messing with the 3rd party code.

**Edit**: I correctly updated my question and changed my typos.

The root element has a min-height, and not a height property set. I think this is the root of the issue. adding a height property solves the issue. I wonder if there is any way to solve my problem without having to modify the root element.

In case there is not, I will have to modify the third party code.

In any case, I find confusing how a property on the grandparent (root) influences the layout of its grand child (iWantToBeBig), even though the childs layout (mainContent) stays exaclty the same.

Comment: It should work, you just have a typo `.iWanntToBeBig` should be `iWantToBeBig`

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I corrected my typo. It is still not working on my page, even though the snipset works fine. I will update my question with more of the third party's css.

Comment: @AlkisMavridis srsly?:D

Comment: You can embed third-parties into the snippet. You use `<script>` and `<link>` tags

Comment: I found the issue. root element has specified a min-height, but not a height. This lays out the children properly, but the problem appears on the grandchild, like my case. Only adding a height on the root element solves my problem. Even though this means that I will have to mess with the 3rd party code, if no other solution is available...

Answer (score 0):

It is working, look at the sample code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjrut7

Try to put all the styling of the `mainContent` element from the third party library in the post. It might be something else causing the problem

Comment: I think I found the problem. The third-party root class had specify min-height instead of height. Adding a height property solves the problem, even though that means that I have to contact them.

Comment: Isn't easy to overwrite their styling using selectors?

Comment: It is, but this component is so often used that I will have to refactor a lot of code. I hoped to solve the problem by manipulating the content only. But until now, I did not find any other solution than editing the grandparent. I still cannot understand why the lack of a height property does not influence at all the children component, but only the grand children. It seams a bit counter intuitive to me...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unfortunatelly on the root element. This means for my case that I cannot solve it without messing with the third party code.

The root element has specified a min-height, but not height, This will correctly layout its children, but its grand children will not be able to use properties such as height:100%.

Adding a height on the root element (equal to its min-height for example) solves the problem.